# Capturing iPhone Volume/Power button event when screen is locked

Tags: ios, xcode, events, button, capture

Im wanting to listen to and capture iPhone volume and or power button events, Then trigger an action in a app running in the background when the screen is locked.

For example Staring and stopping a timer app, volume up to start and then volume down to stop.

this question has been asked in the past but many years ago and back then it was said not to be possible.

but surely there is way if iOS is listening to trigger functions like silent when there is a incoming call.?

Comment: just note that doing so will cause your app to be rejected because you are using the physical buttons not for their intended use. But if you don't care about publishing to the app store then do it

Comment: I didn’t think you were not allowed to use the buttons for other than they were inter for